# timeit takes forever to time a simple operation

Tags: python, list, timeit

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Just trying to compare lookup speeds of list and dict, but `timeit` just takes forever to get results.

```
from timeit import timeit

foo = list(range(10000000))
bar = {x:0 for x in range(10000000)}

timeit('5000000 in foo', globals=globals())
```

I also tried not using `globals` but passing initialisation statements to `setup` within `timeit`, but same result.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `number=` parameter to `timeit()` function to limit *number* of executions:

```
from timeit import timeit

foo = list(range(10_000_000))
bar = {x:0 for x in range(10_000_000)}

print( timeit('5000000 in foo', globals=globals(), number=1) )
```

Prints:

```
0.0755848770004377
```